# byte array to a short

Tags: c

I have an integer val.

```
data[0]=0;
data[1]=0;
data[2]=(val>>8)%256;
data[3]=val%256;
```

How do I do the oposite? How do I take the int from the char array?

Comment: use uint8_t defined in `stdint.h` if you want to store the data byte-by-byte, not chars.

Comment: Instead of using the modulo operator, you can simply mask off the bits using `val & 0xFF`.  This makes your intent clearer and (on most CPU architectures) is more efficient.

Comment: @bla, I doubt it will be faster on any modern pipelined architecture, but it's clearer indeed. Also, I think you can actually just skip any masking and modulo calculus, the upper bits are thrown away by implicit casting.

Answer (score 7):

For unsigned data:

```
val = (data[2] << 8) | data[3];
```

For signed data:

```
val = ((data[2] << 8) & 0xff00) | (data[3] & 0xff);
```

Comment: Can you give us the exact data types of `data` and `val`?  You might be suffering from sign extension.

Comment: Yup; that's my guess too.  If `data` is `signed char *`, and either of `data[2]` or `data[3]` is greater than 127, the upper bits of the result may be filled with 1's.

Comment: @strager maybe you are right. It seems that I am expecting a value ~185 here. How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: @cateof- Use `unsigned char` for `data`, or better yet `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:

```
int myint = mybyte[0]<<24+mybyte[1]<<16+mybyte[2]<<8+mybyte[3];
```

Assuming that's your bit order, and they're all unsigned.  You may have to cast the bytes into ints in order to make sure they don't wrap (11001100 -> 11001100,0000000 instead of 11001100).

A far stranger way (though probably faster) would be something questionable legal with pointers:

```
int * myintp= mybyte;
int myint = *myintp;
```

I've not tested this at all, but it should theoretically work, assuming that the lengths work out, etc.  It's still probably not a good idea.

Comment: Your pointer casting won't turn out well on a little-endian machine.

Comment: how do I case the bytes into ints in order to make sure they don't wrap?

Comment: @advait: And that is why I said it's a poor choice :P

@cateof: ((int)mybyte[0])<<24+((int)mybyte[1])<<16+...

Or to be very sure, (((int)mybyte[0]) & 0xFF)<<24 + (((int)mybyte[1]) & 0xFF)<<16 + ...
But that is probably not needed, so try it without the AND first.

Answer (score 0):

mod is a pretty expensive operation, particularly for saving a 32-bit int. You probably just want to memcpy. If you're worried about portability throw in a htonl:

```
#include<string.h>

uint32_t x = 12;
char data[4];
memcpy(data, &x, sizeof(x));
```

To go the other way you can just reverse it:

```
memcpy(&x, data, sizeof(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always try a union:

```
typedef union {
    int      i;
    uint8_t  bytes[sizeof(int)];
} int_u;
```

You can use this to turn an `int` into bytes or vice versa.  Be mindful of endian-ness issues, however, if you are using this to transport data between platforms.

Answer (score -3):

Simply iterate through the elements and do a Int.Parse

Comment: `Int.Parse` isn't standard C, nor does it solve the problem here.